# Return 0/1 over url parameter

Tags: php, function, url

i need some help with this .
I want to create a php file with returning 0 or 1 when you open the file with url parameter .

I have this code so far :

```
<?php
function checkID($ID)
{
$allowedID = array('111','123');
if (in_array($ID, $allowedID ))
echo '1';
else
echo '0';   
}
?>
```

When i open the file it only shows me a blank page .
And i have no idea how to use url parameter , like site.com/myphp.php?ID=111

Thanks !

Comment: So how are you calling your checkID() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
function checkID($ID)
{
    $allowedID = array('111','123');
    if (in_array($ID, $allowedID)) {
        echo '1';
    } else {
        echo '0';   
    }
}
checkID($_GET['ID']); 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this , it works but when the ID is allowed the page is blank .

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if ID is in the $_GET array, then check if it matches your defined set:

```
function checkID()
{
    $allowedID = array('111','123');
    if (array_key_exists('ID', $_GET) && in_array($_GET['ID'], $allowedID )) {
        return '1';
    } else {
        return '0';   
    }
}

// run the function
echo checkID();
```

**Edit** - removed the param from the function and echo'd the result

Comment: Your function call without param.

Comment: also you might want to echo the result

Comment: oh just changed return to echo and it worked . Thanks a lot !!